# Do not publish artifact to Nexus if project has not changed

Tags: java, gradle, nexus, multi-project, maven-publish

I have two projects as part of my multi- project build, `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`.

`ProjectA` has a `compile` dependency on `ProjectB`. I also have automatic build number increments, whereby each project contains a `versions.json` file containing the latest build number. I have gradle script that increments this build number on a `gradle publish`.

Now, when a change is made to `ProjectA`, and a `gradle clean publish` is performed, `ProjectB` is also deployed to Nexus, even though it hasn't changed. How can I stop this from happening?

Note that the build is always done from clean since this process happens by our CI server and is always done from a fresh clone, so a solution such as the following does not work:

```
publish {
  onlyIf { jar.didWork }
}
```

How can I ensure that an artifact is onlt published to Nexus if it is different to the latest copy upstream? Perhaps one way to solve this is to not run the `publish` on the dependent project. But how?

Comment: Is ProjectB version incrementing when you make a change to ProjectA?  If no, does your hosted repository in NXRM allow redeploy?

Comment: No, ProjectB version does not change and the artifact repository does not allow redeploy. I have a task that depends on `publish` that increments the build number. So when ProjectA gets published, ProjectB will also get published and the task will run, so the build number will be incremented. I need to not build/publish dependent projects, or stop the task from running on dependent projects somehow.

Comment: I see.  If the build number is incremented as far as NXRM knows, this is new.  IMO your problem lies before NXRM.

Comment: Yes, you are right. So how do I stop the build from propagating down to publishing projects that may not have changed?